# jointjs links no longer attached to ports after loading with graph.fromJSON

Tags: jointjs

I'm saving my graph layout with graph.toJSON and restoring with graph.fromJSON. When restoring a layout that had links between ports on elements originally, the links are no longer attached to the ports, but are instead attached to the element. The ports are still there on the element - but the links aren't attached to them. Like this:

Before `graph.toJSON`:

[image: Prior to graph.toJSON]

After `graph.fromJSON`:

[image: After graph.fromJSON]

I'm quite prepared to believe I'm missing some crucial step somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

jointjs has something called [routers](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.0/joint.html#routers) which compute the path that the link should follow.

Can can check if you're using some custom option on the `paper` when you create the graph and get the json, but when you rerender the graph from the json, the same properties are not set on the `paper` and `graph`.

Also, ensure the width and height available to the graph is same when it was created and when you render it from json. Just to be assured issue doesn't arise because of it.

Other than this, I don't any issue. If the problem, still persist, try filing a bug on their repo.

Comment: It looks like a rendering issue for sure - if you select an item and resize it with the halo (Rappid add-on) the connector jumps back onto the port correctly, so it's possible to restore the correct link just by resizing the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I called the `graph.fromJSON(JSON.parse(data));` at the beginning of my `initializePaper()` function.

After I moved it to the end of this function, everything started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This one almost drove me crazy too; essentially the paper/graph needs to be fully loaded before you start putting elements on the graph or you will start to see strange behavior and things won't look quite right. I solved this by putting a short timeout before loading graph data.